# Adjacent sibling selector:after jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

What would be the proper way to select the following classes in jQuery. I need to select an input class and label:after but it doesn't seem to work. 
These are the selectors that need to be selected.

```
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:after {
  content: "C";
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  width: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 36px;
  transition: margin 0.2s, background 0.2s;
}
```

Here is my attempted jquery selector

```
var toggle = $("input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:after");
toggle.addClass("toggle-color3");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't select a pseudo-element.  You also can't add a class to a pseudo-element.  If you need to style label:after, select the label like this:

```
var toggle = $("input.cmn-toggle-round-flat").next("label");
```

add a class to it:

```
toggle.addClass("toggle-color3");
```

and then use that class within your CSS:

```
label.toggle-color3:after {
  content: "C";
}
```